# I want to get data contains string in json data field

Tags: json, laravel

I have a post table that contains json field 
i want to get all post that contains some string in json array 
for example show all post that contains John in tags field
**laravel**

```
post: [
         +"id": 1,
         +"user_id": 1,
         +"category_id": 1,
         +"title": "post",
         +"description": "post descr",
         +"tags": "{"tags": ["John", "Anna", "Peter"]}",
         +"created_at": null,
         +"updated_at": null,
     ],
```

Answer (score 0):

A regular where can be used to query json fields:

```
$posts = Post::whereJsonContains('tags->tags', 'John')->get();
```

Checkout the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Column not found :(

Comment: Could you add the migration you used to setup the Post table to your question? @arashkenji

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

Post::whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(tags->tags,'John')')->get();